# theme.res file not being created within new "Codename One" projects. [OS- Win10, IDE- Eclipse, Java SDK- 8u321]

Tags: java, codenameone

The theme.res file is not being created in new projects. It is however being created in demo projects. I can copy the file from a demo to my new project, but this is annoying and gives little control over the appearance.

```
Exception: java.io.IOException - /theme.res not found
java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:704)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:668)
    at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initFirstTheme(UIManager.java:1992)
    at com.example.myapp.App.init(App.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:134)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1138)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:933)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deprecated the plugins a while back so you shouldn't use them to create a project. You should use https://start.codenameone.com/ as explained on the Codename One website.

The maven support doesn't need a plugin and works with all IDEs as explained here: https://shannah.github.io/codenameone-maven-manual/

Comment: Thanks. I've encountered errors with this new method now. But I've posted it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820771/errors-importing-and-running-codename-one-maven-project-using-eclipse-windows-1)