# Errors importing and running codename one maven project using eclipse, windows 10, jdk_8u321

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone, maven-plugin

***Downloaded Codename one maven project for eclipse. When I import the project, at the end of the import I get this error:***

[image]

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

***When I run the simulator, I get this failure and error at the end:***

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/hmmmm/Downloads/eclipse-java-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/hmmmm/Downloads/eclipse-java-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/hmmmm/Downloads/eclipse-java-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/hmmmm/Downloads/eclipse-java-2021-09-R-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Users\hmmmm\Desktop\app\EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.8.0_321, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre
Default locale: en_TT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: plain
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\hmmmm\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\hmmmm\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\hmmmm\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\hmmmm\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example.app:app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example.app:app-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example.app:app-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.app:app-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file C:\Users\hmmmm\.codenameone\CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ com.example.app:app:1.0-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\hmmmm\Desktop\app\pom.xml, line 329, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.app:app-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 60, column 19
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 70, column 19
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file C:\Users\hmmmm\.codenameone\CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ com.example.app:app:1.0-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\hmmmm\Desktop\app\pom.xml, line 329, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.app:app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file C:\Users\hmmmm\.codenameone\CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ line 329, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app                                                                [pom]
[INFO] app-common                                                         [jar]
[INFO] app-javase                                                         [jar]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.example.app:app:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [verify]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Project: com.example.app:app-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [verify]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Project: com.example.app:app-javase:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [verify]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.example.app:app >-------------------------
[INFO] Building app 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                          [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.example.app:app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.example.app:app-common >---------------------
[INFO] Building app-common 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Using connector AetherRepositoryConnector with priority 100.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/3.0.0/maven-antrun-plugin-3.0.0.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\hmmmm\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-antrun-plugin\3.0.0\maven-antrun-plugin-3.0.0.pom.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for app 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.009 s]
[INFO] app-common ......................................... FAILURE [08:09 min]
[INFO] app-javase ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-10T16:58:31-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:3.0.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:3.0.0
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:3.0.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:106)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:889)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:659)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:475)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:469)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:159)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1315)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1228)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:384)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:107)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:215)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:161)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.getResponse(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:655)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:481)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:915)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:331)
    ... 34 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: This looks like Java has a problem connecting to the internet to fetch dependencies from Maven central. Are you behind a proxy or have some tools installed preventing a connection?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog
 So far so good. It actually works. I still got the first error dialog when project import had finished, but the project runs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was behind a proxy indeed. I thought of that, but wasn't sure if that contributed to the errors. I tried it without the proxy and it worked as normal. Thanks again.